# Unity humanoid movement

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-community-toolkit, unity3d-gui

Some Animations I import develop issues when I change the animation type to humanoid.
The problem is that when I change it the animator the  humanoid tends to enter the ground level. So anytime I apply the animation to my game it tends to go below my ground level. You can see it in the image. Besides I’m still learning unity though.

[image]

Comment: I dont see an image.

Comment: They won’t allow me send an image. I’m new on here

Comment: @Eddge could you help me on that? So I could send an image